# The best way to use same code more than once? /PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, class, app-code

I'm pretty new in php, but I have a question that I can't find to it a good solution.

I'm comming from `ASP.NET` backround and I'm looking for something like a folder that will contain all the code that I use it more than one time (Like the `App_Code folder` in `ASP.NET`).

Is there something like this in PHP (So I can call a function / class from other page)?

Wish for help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the code in a separate file, say `common.php` or `lib/myfile.php`

Then, just `require()` it:

```
require("common.php");
```

Or you can look at the fancy class loading provided by [Packagist](http://packagist.org) but for the most compatability or simplicity the above method will work

Comment: for a small project `require` is ok. But when your project get bigger autoloading is better.

Comment: I can imagine so. I've never used PHP in a large project, mainly because I don't like it